# Change the User/ Author of the Products

Tags: customization, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a wordpress site, with plugins of Woocommerce and WCFM.

I imported multiple products as an admin and also published them.

As a admin, I would like to assign the products to these vendors. According to the WCFM, the vendors, are actually users with Role - Store Vendor.

Based on a certain value of the product (say product URL),  I would like to assign that to certain vendor. Can this happen programmatically?
Simply put, change the author of the products, based on a certain criteria (product URL), and go through all the products.

Comment: You question need to be more specific and not related to third party plugin or theme. Also show us what you have tried till now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in importer and map vendor IDs to a column named "Store" in a CSV. If you export all of the products, you can use an excel Lookup function to read the URLs and determine the author; then, re-import the file. This is of course, a one-time deal rather than something that will work automatically in the background.